# goroutines deadlock when using global variable

Tags: go, mutex, goroutine

I'm a new learner to Golang, and I'm trying to write this small piece of code for understanding goroutines and mutex.

```
package main

import "time"
import "sync"

var done bool
var mu sync.Mutex

func worker(){
    for{
        println("tick")
        mu.Lock()
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        if done {
            mu.Unlock()//If I place unlock here, deadlock happens
            return
        }
        mu.Unlock();//If I place unlock here, everything is fine
    }
    
}

func main(){
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    println("start")

    go worker()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    mu.Lock()
    done = true
    mu.Unlock()
    println("cancelled")
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}
```

I'm expecting the output looks like this:
start
tick
tick
...
tick
cancelled

However, deadlock happened when I place `mu.Unlock`before return. I wonder how this deadlock happened?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Because that's the logic. You are trying to **unlock** a lock inside a conditional check `if done { .. }`, but `done` will never be `true` since you're not releasing the lock. Go over the steps here:

```golang
    for{
        println("tick")
        mu.Lock()
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        if done {
            mu.Unlock() //If I place unlock here, deadlock happens
            return
        }
    }
```

`for { ..`  You have an endless loop.

`mu.Lock()` It first grabs a lock, and do some processing (`time.Sleep`)

`if done { .. }` This will never be true, since we didn't release the lock so no other thread can update the `done` variable.

loop ends. On the next iteration, the `mu` lock is still locked, so you're in a **deadlock.**

Comment: I'm guessing that if you lock a mutex twice within the same thread(goroutine). Deadlock happens, right?

Comment: You **can't** lock a mutex twice, even by the same goroutine.

Comment: Well you can _attempt_ to lock a lock twice..... the second attempt, will of course block.

Comment: More precisely, you can't lock a Go `sync.Mutex` when it's already locked. Other languages have thread IDs and recursive locks (e.g., a Python RLock) and will count the number of lock calls in the thread. Goroutines have no thread identifier and hence cannot be used this way.